# How to rename file in API 30

Tags: java, android

```
File from = new File("oldPath");
            File to = new File("newPath");

            from.renameTo(to);
```

> above method working in API 28
> But after update to API 30, this method not working now

Comment: There is no queastion and you did not tell the paths.

Comment: You’ll have to use DocumentFile, DocumentsContract or ContentResolver apis with correct uri.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a permission related thing; i.e. you were once permitted to move that file, but no longer.  What are the actual paths?   And how precisely does it "not work"?  Note the android-related limitations here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#renameTo(java.io.File)